# How-to check if java class was run from within the NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans

Background: I use a command line based user-interface to use ( = mostly test ) utility classes. When I use the NetBeans IDE I make use of 'Eric's console' which enables command line i/o from within NetBeans.

**Question**: I want to check if a class has been run from within the NetBeans IDE or not. Is this possible and if so how to implement this?

Comment: Your "background" part is hardly applicable to the "question" part. In any case, why don't you just configure NetBeans to launch your application passing it a `/you_are_being_run_by_netbeans` parameter?

Comment: I believe "Eric's console" should handle that for you anyway, and use standard console I/O if NetBeans classes aren't somehow available.

Comment: @Romain fyi "Eric's Console" does not use NetBeans classes it just emulates a dos command in a swing window.

Comment: @ndroock1 Your question's phrasing makes it look like it pipes into a NetBeans plugin, hence my confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect `System.getProperty("user.dir")` which is where the application is run from.

Comment: Note that this is a heuristic.  Code defensively.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.console()` to check if it running on Netbeans or not.
The `System.console()` will return `null` if Application running on Netbeans, but it will return Console Object, if App running on Console.

So we can make check like this:

```java
if(System.console() == null){
    System.out.println("This Application is running on Netbeans");
} else {
    System.out.println("This Application is running on Console");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to do this is to explicitly tell your program either by passing a special argument or a system property which your code then acts accordingly upon.

Otherwise you have to rely on heuristics which eventually will break.

Comment: Yes, heuristically it is possible, but as you, it will eventually break.

Comment: @ndroock1 I do not understand what you tell me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible unless you add a specific command line parameter to indicate that the programm is started from NetBeans.